# How do I add aliases to names in Trello?

Tags: trello

Is it possible to add an alias to a name in Trello, so that I can know who the person is?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible at the moment for one user to tag an alias onto another user, but associated with a user account is a *full name* and a *username* and an *avatar*, so they have plenty of opportunity to present a real world identity and a username of their choice. Assuming they wish to be 'known' in the first place.

To be honest other users identities are not exactly well hidden in my opinion - when you hover over a user's avatar, a tooltip shows `Full name (username)`. For this to be useful, I'd strongly recommend that for the benefit of team participation, users enter their real name in the 'full name' field.

Comment: That does not technically solve the problem at all...

Comment: True - but it answers your question - ie *It's not possible*